# Differentiate $\log_{10}x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

My attempt:

> $\eqalign{
>   & \log_{10}x = {{\ln x} \over {\ln 10}}  \cr 
>   & u = \ln x  \cr 
>   & v = \ln 10  \cr 
>   & {{du} \over {dx}} = {1 \over x}  \cr 
>   & {{dv} \over {dx}} = 0  \cr 
>   & {v^2} = {(\ln10)^2}  \cr 
>   & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {{\left( {{{\ln 10} \over x}} \right)} \over {2\ln 10}} = {{\ln10} \over x} \times {1 \over {2\ln 10}} = {1 \over {2x}} \cr} $

---

The right answer is: ${{dy} \over {dx}} = {1 \over {x\ln 10}}$ , where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $\log_{10} = C\ln$ (with $C=\frac{1}{\ln 10}$), $\log_{10}^\prime = C\ln^\prime$ (derivation is a linear operator, $(Cf)\prime= Cf^\prime$ for any constant $C$). That is, $\frac{d\log_{10}}{dx}(x) = C\frac{d\ln}{dx}(x)= \frac{C}{x}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You made one small mistake when you looked at $v^2$. Note that: $$(\ln {v})^2\ne 2\ln(v)$$That would only be true if the expression was: $$\ln\bigl(v^2\bigr)$$

Comment: Keep in mind, the method others are pointing out is more efficient. I just wanted to point out where the problem with your method was.

Answer (score 6):

Elaborating a bit on @Clement's answer, $\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}\right)'=\frac{1}{\ln 10}(\ln x)'$, because $\frac{1}{\ln 10}$ is a constant.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that's an interesting way to look at it

Answer (score 6):

$${\rm{lo}}{{\rm{g}}_{10}}x = {{\ln x} \over {\ln 10}} = \dfrac{1}{\ln(10)}\ln x$$

No need for the chain rule, in fact, that would lead you to your mistakes, since $\dfrac 1 {\ln(10)}$ is a constant.

So we differentiate only the term that's a function of $x$: $$\dfrac{1}{\ln(10)}\frac d{dx}(\ln x)= \dfrac 1{x\ln(10)}$$

Comment: @amWhy: Correction looks great to me! +1

Answer (score 2):

if someone doesn't know how to write $\log_{10}x$ in simpler form then there is a direct differential formula:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log_ax=\frac 1x\log_{e}{a}$$
so here $$\frac{d}{dx}\log_{10}x=\frac 1x\log_e10$$
using identity :
$$\log_nm=\frac{1}{\log_mn}$$

we can write:
$$\frac 1x\log_e10\implies\frac 1{x\log_{10}e}$$

Comment: The first line is incorrect; the rhs of the first line should read $\frac{1}{x\log_e{\bf a}}$. Similarly on the second line.

Comment: @Daryl +1 for mention my typo